# CSS Transform Rotated Images Not Showing in Safari

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari, css-transforms

I'm noticing on iPhone that the images for the "subscribe" widget and the "Spark" widget are not displaying the images inside of them. The images are using CSS Transforms to rotate them. I'm unable to pinpoint what the issue is, any guidance at all would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with iPhone, the height of the image is set to 0px and not changed for smaller widths. You will get the same effect if you reload the page on any browser while on a small window width.